# SSH system name alias (to prevent typing out the ip)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

If you've seen my previous posts, you would know that I recently finished installing/basic setup of SSH to my ubuntu based server. I've seen one of my dev friends use the following command to get into his server:

```
user@linux ~$ ssh amy
```

How do I make it so I can do something similar (in my case `ssh dc`) to get into my server easier? Remembering the IP and port number is real annoying...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `~/.ssh/config` to create connection profiles, which can set the address, the username, the port number, or any other parameters that are settable from the command line:

```
Host dc
    Hostname 2001:db8:4321::abcd:efgh
    Port 5453
    User fred
```

This of course only works on your own computers. If you need a mechanism that works from absolutely everywhere, then you need DNS, i.e. use a domain name (whether your own or a subdomain under a friend's domain). Of course it would still be `ssh dc.mydomain.com` in that case, and DNS cannot help you with ports or usernames – only IP addresses.